# Is there a way to create a bar graph visualization with plotly or python where the y-axis is 24hour range and x-axis is all the weekdays?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I'm trying to create a visualization of a group of people's work hours (ideally with plotly because I want to incorporate a drop down bar that allows user to switch between timezones in the US and adjust hours accordingly). The x-axis would be the weekdays, y-axis the 24hour range, the bar graphs would go down vertically (would show someone working i.e. from 7am-3pm Mon-Fri) and can overlap with other's work hours (I know I would need to use an opacity argument).

so far I've tried numerous things, the closest are the following codes:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()

week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

# Add Traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=week_days,
           name="Nicole",
           #line=dict(color="#33CFA5")
          ))
#fig.update_yaxes(strftime("%H:%M"))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="None",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, False]},
                           {"title": "CSI Work Hours",
                            #"annotations": []
                           }]),
                dict(label="MT",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, False, False]},
                           {"title": "MT",
                            #"annotations": high_annotations
                           }]),
                dict(label="PT",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, True, True]},
                           {"title": "PT",
                            #"annotations": low_annotations
                           }]),
                dict(label="HT",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, True, True]},
                           {"title": "HT",
                            #"annotations": high_annotations + low_annotations
                           }]),
            ]),
        )
    ])

# Set title
fig.update_layout(title_text="CSI")

fig.show()
```

[image: plotly graph of above code]

```
#create plot with days of week as x-axis, 24hr range as y-axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
#ax.plot_date(start_date, end_date, ydate=True, xdate=False)

#number of days in week 7, set to x-axis to display all week days
l = range(0,7)
week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

# reformat axis ticks to only show hour/min on y-axis; label x-axis w/ week days
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.axis import Axis
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator())
ax.invert_yaxis()
#ax.set_yticks(t)
ax.set_xticks(l)
ax.set_xticklabels(week_days)
```

![plot#2 of above code][2]

for the actual data points, I tried creating dictionaries for each person or for each time zone, but I couldn't figure out how to plot lists for data points.

```
person1_hrs_dict = {'Monday' : [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
              'Tuesday' : [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
              'Wednesday' : [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
              'Thursday' : [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
              'Friday' : [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
              'Saturday' : 0,
              'Sunday' : 0
             }
MT_hrs_dict = {"weekdays":["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
 "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
"csi team": ["person1","person2",etc],
"work hours": []}
#I don't think MT_hrs_dict would work since some people work weekends and have some weekdays off.
#I think I'm overcomplicating it or maybe creating text document might be easier?
```

Here is the new attempt:

```
employees = list(["Paige","Julissa","Jessica","David","Jamila","Eric Pt",
                 "Nicole","Jackie","Christian","McKay","Eric Pxt","Krissa",
              "Brynn","Jordan","Ethan","Andrew","Tysen","Austin","Dalin",
                "Alex","Pierce","Astha","Spencer","Edgar","Mike","Tiffany"])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.product(
        pd.date_range("18-oct-2021", periods=7, freq="D").values, employees
    ),
    columns=["date", "employee"],
)

csi_times=["8:00:00.00","11:00:00.00","8:00:00.00","9:00:00.00",
            "10:00:00.00","8:00:00.00","7:00:00.00","9:00:00.00",
            "8:00:00.00","14:30:00.00","9:00:00.00","7:00:00.00",
            "8:00:00.00","9:00:00.00","9:00:00.00","7:00:00.00",
            "22:00:00.00","22:00:00.00","9:00:00.00","15:00:00.00",
            "10:00:00.00","9:00:00.00","8:00:00.00","22:00:00.00",
            "10:00:00.00","7:30:00.00"]
times_format = '%H:%M:%S.%f'
worked_hours = []
n=8
for time in csi_times:
    given_times = datetime.strptime(time, date_format_str)
    final_times = given_times + timedelta(hours=n)
    final_time_strngs = final_times.strftime('%H:%M')
    worked_hours.append(final_time_strngs)
#print(csitimes)

df["start"]=csi_times*7

df["hoursworked"]= worked_hours*7

df["dow"]=df["date"].dt.strftime("%a")

#8,11,8,9,10,8,7,9,8,14,9,7,8,9,9,7,22,22,9,15,10,9,8,22,10,7
#create the figure as bar graph
fig = px.bar(df, x="dow", y="hoursworked", base="start", color="employee", barmode="group",
      labels={
                     "dow": "Days of Week",
                     "hoursworked": "Working Hours",
                     "employee": "CSI Team"
                 },
      title="CSI Working Hours")

#reverse y axis so it starts with 0 (12AM) and goes down to 23(11PM)
fig.update_layout(
   yaxis = dict(autorange = "reversed")
)
fig.show()
```

[image: new plotly graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- doing what you describe is simple.  Have done what you describe, constructed a dataframe with *dayofweek, start, hours worked, employee*
- this then becomes a simple bar plot, where *dayofweek* is *xaxis* and **yaxis** a bar that shows start hour and hours worked

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

employees = list("ABC")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.product(
        pd.date_range("18-oct-2021", periods=7, freq="D").values, employees
    ),
    columns=["date", "employee"],
).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(
        start=np.random.randint(1, 10, len(d)),
        hoursworked=lambda d: np.random.randint(3, 10, len(d)),
        dow=d["date"].dt.strftime("%a")
    )
)

px.bar(df, x="dow", y="hoursworked", base="start", color="employee", barmode="group")
```

[image]

#### data frame sample

| date | employee | start | hoursworked | dow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-18 00:00:00 | A | 3 | 5 | Mon |
| 2021-10-18 00:00:00 | B | 3 | 5 | Mon |
| 2021-10-18 00:00:00 | C | 4 | 4 | Mon |
| 2021-10-19 00:00:00 | A | 6 | 6 | Tue |
| 2021-10-19 00:00:00 | B | 1 | 8 | Tue |
| 2021-10-19 00:00:00 | C | 9 | 5 | Tue |
| 2021-10-20 00:00:00 | A | 7 | 4 | Wed |
| 2021-10-20 00:00:00 | B | 2 | 4 | Wed |
| 2021-10-20 00:00:00 | C | 1 | 4 | Wed |
| 2021-10-21 00:00:00 | A | 3 | 6 | Thu |

#### data frame construction - simpler syntax

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.product(
        pd.date_range("18-oct-2021", periods=7, freq="D").values, employees
    ),
    columns=["date", "employee"],
)
df["start"] = np.random.randint(1, 10, len(df))
df["hoursworked"] = np.random.randint(3, 10, len(df))
df["dow"] = df["date"].dt.strftime("%a")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this! I have a few questions if you don't mind clarifying some things for me. I'm familiar with python, but not so much with pandas.
1)itertools - does this help loop through the days of the week for each employee within this data frame?
2) .pipe, lambda d: d.assign - I'm not familiar with this at all, but based on the context I'm assuming its assigning the random hours to employees. can I change this to add specific hours for specific employees? would it work if I used a list?
3)would I also be able to add timezones for specific employees start hours?

Comment: your points 1 & 2 are correct.  I'm just using it to build all permutations of 7 days and employees as rows.  other approaches could be used,   Once rows are in place, assign random values to start and hours worked.  could have done `df = ...` `df["start"] = np.random.randint(1, 10, len(df))`.  I have used *start* as an *int* rather than `time()`.  to your point you could record each employees timezone.  I'd be more inclined to use UTC

Comment: I think I need more clarification regarding `lambda d: d.assign` and what **d** is. I tried doing `start=[dt.time(8,0).strftime('%H:%M'),...]` (there are 26 within the list), but not sure how to set that length to match the index? I think once I understand that I can figure out how to add the timezones

Comment: have updated answer with alternate syntax for dataframe construction

Comment: So, I'm a bit stumped again. I've added a pic and the code I have now to the original post. For some reason everyone's start hours are at 16:00, yet when I print the df["start"] which is the base in the Plotly Express, it shows the correct assigned start times. What am I missing/messing up?

Comment: you code is not runnable,  for example depends on undefined variable `employees`. I recommend you ensure you are asking about something that is runnable

Comment: oh sorry I do have employees defined I just didn't include it in my code snippet for some reason. it has the list of all the employees shown in the newest plot legend

Comment: ok, I would help if I could.... but still I can't as I have to try and second guess how to make your snippet run :-( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example

Comment: I added the employees to my code so I think it should work now. If not, thank you so much for helping me get this far!! I've learned a lot and really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here it is a non-Plotly solution, just Matplotlib.

The reader could appreciate how the correct spacing and positioning of the bars is easily computed in the code.

```
In [102]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     ...: from random import randint
     ...: 
     ...: # faking some data
     ...: dow = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri'.split()
     ...: emps = 'Concetta Laura Gerry Ceci'.split()
     ...: data = {e:{d:(randint(0,12),randint(6,12))for d in dow}for e in emps}
     ...: 
     ...: # computing the appropriate width of the bars
     ...: nbars = len(emps)
     ...: d = 0.25   # distance between bars in terms of the bar width
     ...: total_width = 0.80 # total width of the horizontal stack of bars
     ...: # total_width = nbars*w + (nbars-1)*d*w →
     ...: w = total_width/(nbars+(nbars-1)*d)
     ...: origin = -total_width/2
     ...: 
     ...: # Plotting
     ...: x = range(len(dow))
     ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     ...: for n, (emp, hours) in enumerate(data.items()):
     ...:     xn = [_+origin+n*(1+d)*w for _ in x]
     ...:     bottoms, heights = zip(*hours.values())
     ...:     ax.bar(xn, heights, width=w,
     ...:            bottom=bottoms, align='edge', label=emp)
     ...: # add background to groups of bars
     ...: ax.bar(x, 24, (total_width+1)/2, bottom=0, zorder=0, alpha=0.15)
     ...: # fixing x tick labels
     ...: ax.set_xticks(range(len(dow)))
     ...: ax.set_xticklabels(dow)
     ...: # fix y axis
     ...: ax.set_ylim((-0.50, 24.50))
     ...: ax.set_yticks(range(0, 25, 2))
     ...: # 
     ...: fig.legend()
     ...: plt.show()
```